# On Heroku web apps, how to redirect from users from .herokuapp.com to custom domain?

Tags: node.js, http, heroku

I am using NodeJS, specifically, I am using the tutorial code from node-js-getting-started. So I have a custom domain, but the default heroku domain is also active, and I would like to have the custom domain be the only one in use. Heroku said to do this.

> Your app’s Heroku domain always remains active, even if you set up a custom domain. If you want users to use the custom domain exclusively, your app should send HTTP status 301 Moved Permanently to tell web browsers to use the custom domain. The Host HTTP request header field will show which domain the user is trying to access; send a redirect if that field is example.herokuapp.com.

I don't really understand how to do this. I'm guessing I have to change something in the index.js file.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the route is "/" or actually any route you should redirect it to your domain with code 301.

Try something like this.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()


self.app.all(/.*/, function(req, res, next) {
  var host = req.header("host");
  if (host.match(/^herokuapp\..*/i)) {
    res.redirect(301, "http://www." + host + req.url); 
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: It actually started to work, without me changing the file. It may have to do with a redirect URL I was using in my domain registrar. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So now If user goes into domain.herokuapp.com does he/she gets redirected to domain.com?

Comment: Yep. I think I’ll test it on another web app and confirm what it was that made it start working.

Comment: So I'm not sure why exactly it's working. I used the redirect 301 function, but it didn't work (chrome said the website redirected too many times). But after I reverted back to normal, the redirects started working.